# Is there a "non affecting" interaction?

Tags: python, selenium, class

My program clicks through the buttons in a list via classes and the list always shows 10 only people at a time. When I'm at the third last button, the list updates itself and shows 3 new buttons and so it goes on. But some buttons have a other class, that i used to skip and the problem is that, when i skip the last 3 buttons because of the other class they have, the list doesn't update itself because there is no interaction with them. My question is, is there any kind of interaction that doesn't affect anything but would let the program go on?

*I hope i explained my problem well.*

**At the moment the program just skips the wrong class**

```
for i in range (1, 41):
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     ']").click()
    except:
        continue
```

the class i want to interact with **class="sqdOP  L3NKy    _8A5w5    "**

Comment: Please provide the link to the page you working with, including the buttons you are talking about

Comment: There's no way for us t know that.  Remember tthat Selenium is just simulating human actions.  How would you, as a human, move to the next page?

Comment: [link](https://www.instagram.com/p/CLMCNSenf-E/) Instagram , u need to click on the likes to see what i mean @Eliyahu